How to get the tfjs model movenet singlepose-lightning-4 in INT8？
This is the smallest tfjs movenet model now movenet/tfJs/singlepose-lightning,but I want get a samller one.
I try to convert it to quantize_uint8 follow this tfjs-converter,but not successed.
I want to know that if tfjs could load int8 model,and how to covert any source model to get it,if not,I just give up.
